# how to access each pod in a cluster over the api

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment layout where there would be various pods (each pod dedicated for each user has a service listens on a particular port). I need to give customer access to their pod directly without revealing the specific port and other secure stuff like cluster certificate details to the user of each pod. Should I go about over vs the other or would it even work?

a) How can I do that over the api server ?
b) Can I create a custom pod access service with a custom certificate to handle all pod access requests.
c) Or do I need a CNI plugin to assign each pod a public ip hosting everything on a cloud vpc?

Comment: If you provide a direct access to the pod then what would stop the user from getting information about cluster ip/port and certificates? You have to limit the access to a user or an area, maybe a jail.

Comment: well, it is direct access to the api running on that , not actually being able to ssh into the pod

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Please describe your goal a little bit more detailed.

Comment: think about each pod as a service/user and I wanna expose them to the world so user can use it with their individual api key for the service